# Can't find location project for template file

Tags: templates, resharper

When I specify a different project form the main file it can't find it and the generation process fails. Does Resharper expect a separate project to be in the folder as the original project? My project 'DataAccess' is in a different folder.

The following works find if I remove "DataAccess".

[image]

Else it creates the other files, but doesn't fill them in, and gives the following error...

[image]

Comment: What error message do you get when generation fails? I've just tested this with 9.2 RC2, and it works as expected.

Comment: Nothing precise. I have updated the question.